# How can I get one response for different API pages with useSWR?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, swr

I am using an API URL that has different data depend on the page URL, but I want to get all the pages URLs in one call, but not getting any data, except when I try to get only one page. Please can someone please help me out?

Here is my code:

```
function arrayFetcher(urlArr) {
    const fetcher = (url) => axios.get(url).then((res) => res.json());
    return Promise.all(urlArr.map(fetcher));
}
    
let urlArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    urlArray.push(`https://api.google.com/page=250&page=${i}&sparkline=false`);
}

const { data } = useSWR(urlArray, arrayFetcher);
    
{data && console.log(data)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing an array as the key parameter to `useSWR`, each item in the array will be its own argument in the `arrayFetcher` function. This means that when you're trying to access `urlArr` inside `arrayFetcher` you're only accessing the first URL of the `urlArray`, and not the full array itself.

A possible solution is to [pass an object](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/arguments#passing-objects) as the key parameter in `useSWR`, which contains `urlArray`.

```js
const fetcher = (url) => {
    return axios.get(url).then((res) => res.json());
};

const arrayFetcher = ({ urlArray }) => {
    // Get `urlArray` from object param
    return Promise.all(urlArray.map(fetcher));
};

const Component = () => {
    let urlArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        urlArray.push(`https://api.google.com/page=250&page=${i}&sparkline=false`);
    }

    // Pass `urlArray` inside object as the key
    const { data } = useSWR({ urlArray }, arrayFetcher); 
    console.log(data);

    // Rest of the component
};
```

Comment: Ok thanks but i just tried it and getting undefined

Comment: The above works for me. Make sure you're looking at the logs in the browser's console. Check the following example in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-hodgkin-nwb0x3.